# Angularjs routing throws 404 without #

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, ngroute

I am creating a website with AngularJS and I am using the ngRoute module to handle page requests.

In my `app.config` function I have setup the routing as follows:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/index.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    }).when('/testpage', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/test.html',
        controller: 'testController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

When I try to access the test page, on my MAMP local server, by adding a `#` before the page name like this: `http://dev.mysite.com:8888/#testpage` everything works fine.

However, if I don't add the `#` before the page name, like this: `http://dev.mysite.com:8888/testpage` I get a 404 error.

I have added `<base href="/">` to the `<head>` of my index.html page that contains the `<div ng-view>` tag.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks for the # symbol to handle routing.  Everything after the # symbol is interpreted by the routing function.  No # symbol, no angular route.  If you can run in Html5 mode, then you can turn this off, but to work with older browsers, it is needed.