# angular route not working, throw page not found error

Tags: angularjs, routes

in index.html

```
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

controller

```
angular.module("testCtrl",[]).controller('TestController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.Myname = "my first route";
}]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('testApp',["ngRoute", "testCtrl"]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when("/",{
            templateUrl: "Views/main.html"
        })
        .when("/details",{
            templateUrl: "Views/details.html",
            controller : TestController
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : "/"
        });
}]);
```

my homepage loads fine but with some reason /details show error like --- No webpage was found for the web address: http://127.0.0.1:8080/details

I am new to angular and I am learning. I am not able to understand whats wrong ..do we have any tools to debug route error? I am using angular 1.5.8 version for now.

server console - "GET /details" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: In case of beginner like me - you need to add # in html before url  -referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088017/angularjs-routing-throws-404-without

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that TestController isn't defined in app.js. You should use the controller name as a string, like so.

```
    .when("/details",{
        templateUrl: "Views/details.html",
        controller : "TestController"
    })
```

See this plunk for a working example.
https://plnkr.co/edit/xi20MmchJY6TO1SG2o0d?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I think you have omitted the dependency on ngRoute:

```
angular.module('testCtrl', ['ngRoute'])...
```

Are you referencing ng-app in your HTML as well (can't see your HTML code)

Presumably you have included your scripts in the HTML page too?